# Form Upload Error After Changing Server

Tags: php

I had a working upload form and then recently bought a dedicated hosting plan (GoDaddy - yes, evil I know) for the site that I had been working on on a pre-existing plan. However, although the file structure is exactly the same with full write permissions, the upload no longer works, but the database is updated, despite the DB only being updated if an image is present. I don't understand why the file is no longer being uploaded:

```
if ($state == "post") {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
if(! empty($_FILES['file']['name'][file])) {
    $allowed_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $upload_extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'][file]));
    if (in_array($upload_extension, $allowed_extensions)) {
    $loop = true;
    $im = null;
    while ($loop) {
        $rand_count = 0;
        while ($rand_count != 10) {
            $rand = rand(1,9);
        $im = $im . $rand;
        $rand_count++;
        }
        $image = $im.".".$upload_extension;
        if (!file_exists("images/posts/" . $image)) {
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][file]);
        if ($height > $width)
                        $width_n = 160; $height_n = $height/$width*$width_n;
        else
            $height_n = 160; $width_n = $width/$height*$height_n;

            $tmp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_n, $height_n);
        if (($upload_extension == "jpeg") || ($upload_extension == "jpg"))
                        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][file]);
        elseif ($upload_extension == "png")
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][file]);
        //tmp_upload 
        imagecopyresampled($tmp_image, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_n, $height_n, $width, $height);
        $path = "images/posts/".$image;
        imagejpeg($tmp_image, $path, 100);
                    $stmt = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_body, post_image) VALUES ('$title', '$body', '$image')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con, $stmt))
                        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            $loop = false;
        header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

`images/posts` exists on the new server.

Comment: You're sure about those folder permissions?

Comment: Check temp file upload path in php.ini

Comment: using relative paths is sometimes prohibited at certain providers. That could be the case here. On my side, i always use full paths to upload files....

Comment: @Salim - you can't access GoDaddy php.ini files, only make new ones that overwrite the existing. It worked on the other GoDaddy hosting plan, which presumably uses the same default php.ini file.

Comment: Also your accessing `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][file]` in a deprecated way, you should use `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['file']`, also your query might break if you dont escape. use prepared querys.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you, it's still in the production stage, (BETA if you will), everything like that will be sorted soon.

Comment: Does GoDaddy really allow 777? Most hosts won't, at least on shared hosting.

Comment: It appears not, it wasn't saving the settings, but it's now (definitely) 705, the same as the previous directory on the other hosting plan that worked. I've also tried full paths, but to no avail. @j08691

Answer (score 0):

Your using the `$_FILES` in a completely wrong manner. In every instance which you use it you need to remove the trailing `[file]`

ie

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][file]
```

becomes

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: <input type='file' name='file[file]' class='block3_upload' accept='image/*' required>

The file array element is called file.